# Can't get dashed line in Seaborn

Tags: python, plot, seaborn

I'm trying to plot two lineplots in the same graph in Databricks and I would like to make one of the lines dashed.

I tried

```
#plot total fed and total programmed
  sns.lineplot(data = data, x = "timestamp", y="total_programmed",  linestyle='dashed',  ax=axes[0], label="A")
  sns.lineplot(data = data, x = "timestamp", y="total_fed", color = "darkgreen", ax=axes[0], label="B")
```

Both lines remain solid. I also tried "--" and variations on that, but the result remains the same. What other options are there?

[image]

Comment: Seaborn 0.11.1, Matplotlib 3.3.4; cannot replicate the issue.

Comment: Yes, it works fine. Maybe you're doing something after these two lines of code that (re)sets the styles? Having the whole code related to the plot might prove useful.

Comment: It turns out there was an older version of seaborn on my cluster so the problem is fixed. Thanks for your input.